# Mapping from table to entity on non-unique column

Tags: entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a table definition which looks like this. I do not have the luxury to change the column defn.

table definition

```
Table FOO{
    F_ID NUMBER, -- PK
    CODE VARCHAR2(10), -- NON UNIQUE
    F_NAME VARCHAR2(10)
}


Table BAR{
    B_ID NUMBER, -- PK
    CODE VARCHAR2(10), --NON UNIQUE
    B_NAME VARCHAR2(10)
}
```

I need to map this to two entities.
Please note that the relationship is one to many. that is, one Foo can have multiple Bars from an entity point of view.

However,
the same code, which is the common column is non unique in both tables, and can have multiple values in both tables.

I know this can be solved using a join afterwards, but the Bar information is required for every Foo object that gets loaded up. 
Is there a way to map this naturally using ORM using a join on the common column code?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
class Foo{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "F_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "F_NAME")
    private String fName;

    @Column(name = "CODE", nullable = false)
    private String code;

    //What should be the join condition?
    private List<Bar> bars; 
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR")
class Foo{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "B_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "B_NAME")
    private String bName;

    //Is this required?
    //private String code;

}
```